# Error starting JobHistoryServer on Cloudera Manager

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I installed Cloudera Manager 5.13.

While installing and running for the first time YARN.. I had the following error

```
Error starting JobHistoryServer
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://vmi150132.contaboserver.net:8020/user/history/done]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.tryCreatingHistoryDirs(HistoryFileManager.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.createHistoryDirs(HistoryFileManager.java:618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.serviceInit(HistoryFileManager.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory.serviceInit(JobHistory.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:239)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=mapred, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:240)
```

[.... and other rows of Stack exception errors]

So basically the problem is the permission of the HDFS folders.

Something like: 
`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /`
will fix the error.

But my question is... Wouldn't be unsafe? Why Cloudera doesn't handle this permissions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the Job History server would be owned by `mapred` and if you want to see the exact permissions you should refer to:

[Deploying MapReduce v2 (YARN) on a Cluster - Step 8: Create the history Directory and Set Permissions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_cluster_deploy.html#topic_11_4_9)

> This is a subdirectory of the staging directory you configured in Step 4. In this example we're using /user/history. Create it and set permissions as follows:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/history
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /user/history
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown mapred:hadoop /user/history
```